# RoR: Accessing :through attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to rails and working in this app where an User can create many Events. Many Users can be invited to these Events, therefore I have the following Models:

User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :events, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Event:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many   :event_guest
  has_many   :guests, :through => :event_guest, :source => :user
end
```

Event_Guest:

```
class EventGuest < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event
end
```

What I am looking for is being able to access (and add) the guest users to an event, for which I've tried all the variations I could thing of "Event.find(1).guests", only to get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: event_guests.event_id: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "event_guests" ON "users"."id" = "event_guests"."user_id" WHERE "event_guests"."event_id" = ? AND "users"."event_id" = 1
```

My event_guest migration was the following:

```
create_table :event_guest do |t|
     t.belongs_to :user, index: true
     t.belongs_to :event, index: true
end
```

Comment: Edit your post to show us your `event_guest` migration. Looks like you didn't add the id's to it.

Comment: @ryank Added already

Comment: Ok. It's been a while since I've used ActiveRecord, but shouldn't `has_many :event_guest` be plural, like `has_many :event_guests`?

Comment: @RyanK Yes, you're right! Still getting the same error though, might be the "join"? I've tried the following sentence, could be wrong too:
Event.find(1).guests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Dharam mentioned, your naming convention is incorrect.  You need to rename the event_guest table.

```
$ rails g migration rename_event_guest_table
```

And then the migration looks like this:

```
def change
  rename_table :event_guest, :event_guests
end
```

You then need to update your event.rb model to be

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many   :event_guests
  has_many   :guests, :through => :event_guests, class_name: 'User'
end
```

And your user.rb model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :event_guests, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :events, through: :event_guests
end
```

Move the dependent destroy off the events association and to the event_guests relationship.  You don't want to destroy the event just because one guest isn't going...

Comment: Had to change the second _"has many"_ in event to `has_many :guests, :through => :event_guests, :source => :user` , but it worked perfectly! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding self.table_name = "event_guest" to EventGuest as that's what you have in migration which is contrary to rails expectation of "event_guests" from the model name.